# How to redirect the cmd output of a second batch instance in Java

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

In Java, i want to call a batch file which requires admin privileges and print the output to the console. I have managed to redirect the output of a single batch file. But, in order to run the batch file with admin privileges, i had to put the following lines in the batch file:

```
set "params=%*"
cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && exit /B )
```

Because of this, when running the batch file with the code from above, firstly, it is starting a new instance of himself. So this why i am thinking that the cmd redirect is not working properly, because there is two instance of the batch (and i need the output from the second instance).

This is the code that i am using to redirect the console output, but it works only for one instance of batch:

```
String cmd = "C:\\Users\\uidq9340\\Desktop\\sdf\\test.bat";
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = r.exec(cmd);

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
pr.getInputStream() ));
String s ;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.appendLogText(s + "\n");
System.out.println(s);
}

pr.waitFor();
```

I have searched for similar questions, but nothing found so far. If anyone can give me a little help to redirect the cmd output of a second instance, i would appreciate a lot!

Comment: @xerx593: that's wrong. `Process.getInputStream()` is indeed the _output_ from the process you run which is _input_ to your Java code, whereas `Process.getOutputStream()` is for _output_ from Java and _input_ to the process; see the javadoc.

Comment: Tamas: your problem is not the second batch in itself (I can do multiple levels of batch, or cmd, fine), but the intervening WSH. AFAICT ShellExecute in WSH always creates a new console -- even the 'cscript' personality which already has a console -- so its output isn't connected to you (also input if that mattered). You could change the batch so it redirects the output (from fsutil) to a _disk file_ under a known name and then have Java look for that file. In this case the output is tiny, but in general to avoid seeing incomplete data, write to a temp name and then rename (atomically). ...

Comment: ... Also note that if your actual goal was not to run the batch file but just to get the dirty bit, _that_ can be done without elevation and is much easier.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you! i hoped that there is a nicer way to do that, but this will work for sure :D